# Java VisualVM Enable Heap Dump on OOME

Tags: java, profiling, jvisualvm

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/applications_local.html) one could automatically take a heap dump when the application encounters an OutOfMemoryException.
After OutOfMemoryException process just disappear from left menu.
How does this feature works in VisualVM?

Thanks.

---

C:\work\temp>java -XX:HeapDumpPath=c:/work/temp/file.hprof -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -jar example.jar

Comment: You can analyse the heap dump after the program has exited.

Comment: Where could I find it (heap dump)? After generation by hand it appear under process in left hand menu. After 'automatic dump' checkbox is enabled nothing happens.

Comment: Usually, its the working directory of the application.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I know, that option in JVisualVM is equivalent to specifying `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` as a JVM parameter. This causes the JVM to create a heap dump file when it encounters an OutOfMemoryError. This file can be then loaded into JVisualVM (or into a profiler) and analyzed there. The directory where the file is stored is defined by the `-XX:HeapDumpPath` parameter.

See also:

- [Troubleshooting Guide for Java SE 6 with HotSpot VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gdyrr)
- [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)
- [StackOverflow: Using HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542979/using-heapdumponoutofmemoryerror-parameter-for-heap-dump-for-jboss)

Answer (score 3):

Seems application just exited upon OOM. In this case, you must run your app with special `-XX` params. See "dump" params in [JVM documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html). After application dies, you can examine dump in your tool.

Comment: Using same method I can dump heap to file when java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown. Just wonder what is "visual tool" is all about?..

Comment: I guess VisualVM just can't cope with application which going to exit.

Comment: Low tool quality as for me. I would expect it logically to show snapshot in same place regardless process liveness.

Comment: And bug in the documentation. Provided `-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` but  works only with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`

Comment: I found it very unuseful to remove app node from list of processes on process exit too. After OOM happend you can analyze heap dump file with Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool.