# Dump Java heap shortly before OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, profiling, heap-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java VisualVM Enable Heap Dump on OOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311371/java-visualvm-enable-heap-dump-on-oome)

I've got an App that crashes because of an OOME. I would like to create a dump file of the heap shortly before the App crashes. I used `jdump` before to analyse the heap after a few hours of runtime, but nothing suspicious was found. I can run the app in some Eclipse profiler. Is there some way to create a heap dump shortly before a OOME is thrown on a server with a normal (or jdk) installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to dump heap before you run out of memory, you could add a worker thread that periodically polls for memory usage (see [freeMemory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory%28%29)).  When you start running out of memory, you dump heap.

See https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java for how to dump heap from your application.