# SQLException when executing prepared statement in Camel route

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following Camel route definition. Its purpose is to export some records in Informix to CSV.

```
<route id="out">
  <from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1" />
  <to uri="sql:select nro_service, enviado_sap ,estado_transmision from servicio_cab?dataSource=dataSource" />
  <to uri="bean:com.enelint.pangeaenelist.Transformer?method=tocsv(Exchange)" />
  <log message="${body}" />
</route>
```

I'm getting the following error from Informix:

Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select nro_servicio, enviado_sap ,estado_transmision from servicio_cab]; SQL state [IX000]; error code [-79782]; Method can be called only once.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Method can be called only once.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
```

The inner exception is `java.sql.SQLException: Method can be called only once`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you posting pictures of code? Just post the code!

Comment: I've transcribed your image into code and formatted your stack trace. I've also clarified your title to reflect what your problem actually is -- that there's a SQLException when executing the prepared statement in the route. I've removed all of the irrelevant tags as well.

Comment: I couldn't add the block of code, that's why I posted an image. Thanks for the formatting and clarification of my question.

Comment: You can always add code. What you can't do is add images because you don't have enough reputation on this site. Please read the page on [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more information on how to format your code in your posts.

Comment: To be more precise about the error I've experiencing, I should say that the same Camel route worked fine when I connected it to a Postgres DB. The problem seems to appear when connecting to Informix. It seems that the driver had some bug but it's supposed to be fixed by now. I think that people found some kind of workaround for this problem.

Comment: IBM reported this bug:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_406.htm
Apparently, the offending methods getUpdateCount() and getResultSet() are called more than once in the line <to uri="sql:select...>. It seems to me that I won't be able to use Spring Camel here since with Informix since it hides multiple calls to this two methods..any suggestions?

Comment: You could, possibly, write your own component in Camel and use your own classes instead of the built-in. That is, [find](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-sql/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/sql/) the offending implementation and write your own fix. Or look to see if there's a bug filed either with camel or spring-camel and see if they offer a solution.

Comment: Hello Roddy, here is a detailed discussion about the issue involving getResultSet():
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984468/getresultset-should-be-called-only-once-per-result
If you know some workaround for this issue I'll appreciate your help.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reported issue in camel 2.12 was fixed; updating to Camel version 2.20.1 did the trick. Thanks for your help.