# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - One instance of "org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext"

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, out-of-memory, hprof

I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`, upon analyzing the `hprof`, I found that

```
One instance of "org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext" loaded by   
"org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3 @ 0x772dd7f80" 
occupies 8,30,89,712 (29.32%) bytes. 
The memory is accumulated in one instance of 
"java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]" loaded by
"<system class loader>"
```

Using Jboss server.

Found one similar at : [JVM HeapDump: The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436573/jvm-heapdump-the-memory-is-accumulated-in-one-instance-of-java-util-concurrent)
(but related to tomcat)

What is the cause/solution of this problem? Tell me if I should provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using eclipse IDE you can change the VM argument

```
double click on the server > open Lunch Configuration > Arguments > VM Arguments
```

and append below two lines in your VM Arguments field

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

it will sure solve your problem

Comment: PermSize=256m,I cannot change this, doesnt from the issue it appears to be a memory leak from the jboss server side ?

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/thread/148887?_sscc=t than u should go to this link it may be helpful for your

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the questioned error in the secondary Eclipse Application, adding -XX:MaxPermSize=512m in ini won't help. You need to go into debug or run configuration->arguments and add that piece in VM arguments.I also increased others memory limits so:

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms120m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Comment: PermSize=256m,I cannot change this on prod server, doesnt from the issue it appears to be a memory leak from the jboss server side ?