# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while deployed in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I have tried to create a small utility which reads excel. I am using ApachePOI 3.9 library for that. When I executed the code from red hat Jboss, it work fine

but when i deployed the .war in server Jboss 7.1.1 Final and executed I got this error

```
ERROR [stderr] (thread-64) Exception in thread "Thread-64" Exception in thread "server-timer1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check your JVM memory allocation pool parameters. If you are running in standalone mode, you could find it it the JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf.bat

Try setting it to `"JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M "` and restarting your server, this setting comes as default with JBoss EAP6.2

Also, if this doesn't help you could analyse the heap using the Eclipse Memory Analyser  [Find it here](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Answer (score 0):

First step:
  Make sure that the JVM memory settings in your Redhat JBoss and JBoss 7.1.1 are the same. It may be that your Redhat JBoss has a higher memory allocation than JBoss 7.1.1. You might need to raise you jboss 7.1.1 memory settings as mentioned by @amitsalyan.

Second Step:
  Configure your JBoss 7.1.1 to [generate a heapdump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542979/using-heapdumponoutofmemoryerror-parameter-for-heap-dump-for-jboss) for postmartum if the server crashes with Outofmemory error.

Third Step:
  If the server fails again with outofmemory, there may be a memory leak that is caused by the libraries or your code. Use Eclipse MAT tool to find the memory issues and fix them.