# How to monitor Java heap space in JBossAS 6.1.0.Final

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, centos6

We must have a bug in our code, but our production website servers die when JBossAS 6.1.0.Final puts out a ton of error messages saying "OutOfMemory Error: Java heap space".  I'm using a Nagios plugin to watch the jboss server.log for these errors, but that may not give us enough time to take the server off-line.  Servers are Centos 6.5, Java is 1.6.0_32-b32

We used to run JMX Console, but security issues forced us to remove it.

Any suggestions on another way I can find out the heap usage so I can write a better Nagios plugin and be more predictive until we find the problem?

Thanks....Lyle

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Using HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError parameter for heap dump for JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542979/using-heapdumponoutofmemoryerror-parameter-for-heap-dump-for-jboss) for generating a heap dump.

Then you can use a tool such as [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to find out where your memory is going.