# Uninitialized object vs new object

Tags: java, object, hashmap, initialization, out-of-memory

How are these code snippets different from each other:

```
Snippet 1: HashMap map1= abc() ;

Snippet 2: HashMap map2= new HashMap();
           map2 = abc();
```

I'm getting OutOfMemoryError in my application. Can the reason of this error due to the implementation of Snippet 1 in my code?

Edit: Added implementation of abc()

```
public HashMap abc(){
    HashMap  rMap = null;

    StringBuffer  sQuery = new StringBuffer("");

     sQuery.append(" SELECT DISTINCT ABC ,DEF, ");
     sQuery.append(" XYZ, ID, NAME  ");
     sQuery.append(" FROM TABLE1");

    Query query = new Query( sQuery.toString());

    List rList = query.executeSelect();

    if (rList != null && rList.size() > 0) {
        Iterator listIter = rList.iterator();
        Map map = null;
         rMap = new HashMap();
        while (listIter.hasNext()) {
            map = (HashMap) listIter.next();

            String key = map.get("ABC") + "%"+ map.get("DEF")+"%"+map.get("XYZ");
            if( rMap.containsKey(key)){
                LinkedHashMap sMap = (LinkedHashMap) rMap.get(key);
                sMap.put(map.get("ID"), map.get("NAME"));
                 rMap.put(key, sMap);

            }else{
                LinkedHashMap sMap = new LinkedHashMap();
                sMap.put(map.get("ID"), map.get("NAME"));
                 rMap.put(key, sMap);
            }
        }
    }
    return  rMap;
}
```

Comment: NO. Sorry for the long comment :P

Comment: Snippet 2 creates additional HashMap instance that is never used (which means Snippet 1 is better), but without seeing the code of `abc()` it's hard to tell what's causing your OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: At the time `map2 = abc()` is exectuted, first `HashMap`in snippet 2 is elegible for garbage collection, so that's not the problem.

Comment: abc() returns a HashMap of type HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>

Comment: @KLCoder That's not enough information. How often are you calling abc? Does each call to abc produce a new HashMap, or does it return the same instance in each call? Can you show the code of abc?

Comment: How many rows are in the `TABLE1` table?

Answer (score 1):

In `Snippet 2` you create an extra instance which would be eligible for garbage collection on the next statement. So basically they're the same and it shouldn't cause a memory leak.

Try running a profiler to check memory map or increase the heap size.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in another part of your code. 
Try setting an automatic heapdump when a `OutOfMemoryError` occurs. See this [Using HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError parameter for heap dump for JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542979/using-heapdumponoutofmemoryerror-parameter-for-heap-dump-for-jboss)

Then, fire the exception running your code.

Last thing is to analyze the dump with a tool like Eclipse Memory Analyzer https://eclipse.org/mat/ and look for big objects o a big number of instances of small objects.
There are lots of tutorials about how to analyze a memory dump: 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically in snippet 2 at the beginning you just initialize the map2 for nothing.
After second step it will just point to another address and older one will be garbage collected.