# Logging java outofmemoryerror stacktrace console output

Tags: java, logging, out-of-memory

I've encountered OutOfMemoryError in my JAVA program.
It is OK that OutOfMemoryError happened, but I'd like to log it when it happens.
I have used -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError options to detect that it happened, but it doesn't log stacktrace information which is printed to console.
I tried to use redirection to log this console output, but 2>&1, 2>, and all other options failed log this output and it just printed to console.
Is there any way to log this stacktrace information? 
I've been googling and searching in stackoverflow.com but couldn't find answer.
Please advice.

- Heap Dump is not my option, either.
  I don't have so much space so can't risk such huge file :'( 
  I just need to log stacktrace information.

Thank you!

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @WhiteViking I'm using linux :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError parameter for heap dump for JBoss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542979/using-heapdumponoutofmemoryerror-parameter-for-heap-dump-for-jboss)

Comment: @MickMnemonic thanks for answering. I've forgot to mention but HeapDump is not my option, either. :)

Comment: Analysing the stack trace only may not tell you the actual _cause_ of the OOME (only the last failed allocation). Can you profile your application with e.g. [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/)?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I don't know about VisualVM but will try to find out. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

- **Option 1**:
  You could use `OnOutOfMemoryError` hook combined with jstack  to get stacktrace of your process:

  `"-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=jstack -l %p"`

  *note*: on production you most likely will have separate shell script for that to avoid problem with jstack coming from different java versions.
- **Option 2**:
  You could use `setUncaughtExceptionHandler` to catch all exception and check for `OutOfMemoryError` specifically:

  ```
  Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

          @Override
          public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
  ...
  ```

Comment: Wow, that's really helpful. I'll definitely try this. Thanks!