# Increasing Memory with Tomcat 7 is not working. Service won`t start

Tags: tomcat, memory, tomcat7

i have a problem with my Tomcat 7 Memory Settings. 
as long as i set -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m i have no problem. At the moment i go over 1024m the service won't start anymore. is there maybe one that can help me?

set memory to 2048

[image: set memory to 2048]

Tomcat Log: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n03zjwbcerhw4ul/AAD6dAocxTdLcGo6WN7MyqKZa?dl=0

Comment: Did you look in that System Event Log, or directly to Tomcat's `logs/console.out` file? Any error there? Btw. I had run pretty big Liferay instances in my previous job, but never needed PerSize bigger than 512m. Are you sure you need to increase `XX:MaxPermSize` and not `Xmx` (the heap memory)?

Comment: What does the Tomcat log file say? What other memory settings do you have? For better diagnosis you should try to start the tomcat manually as a first try. If theres a OutOfMemoryError you should activate [heap dump creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542979/using-heapdumponoutofmemoryerror-parameter-for-heap-dump-for-jboss) and look into the heap dump to see what uses the memory.

Comment: in that case i have to increase memory size. i have 16GB of RAM. i would like to increase it to 4GB

Comment: I looked in the system eventlog. Found no errors, i looked up different pages for mor information but nothing helped till now. i attached the log files.