# Javafx gif memory leak

Tags: java, javafx, memory-leaks, gif, heap-memory

I am using 4 different animated GIF(640x360) file on my javafx(version 8 update 144) program, but they causes high memory usage and programa crashes. Why GIF files causes to memory leak? If I use PNG or other formats program works normal.

When it crashes prints this message

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: What is your heap size? Perhaps can you simply increase its size.

Comment: Have you [taken a heap dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542979/using-heapdumponoutofmemoryerror-parameter-for-heap-dump-for-jboss)? Have you [analysed it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html)? What did you find? If you haven't, go do that.

Comment: Are you sure of your JavaFX version ? Asking because of [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8117172) ?

Comment: Hi, i`m another guy, using Java 8 u 202 (dev)
Same problem, 20mb gif after loading in JFX is consuming 600mb memory.